Computation of conformal Hubble parameter
I'm trying to calculate the conformal Hubble parameter $\mathcal H$ using Astropy, but I'm unsure about the correct approach. I know that the standard Hubble parameter $H(t)$ is related to the scale factor $a(t)$ by
$$
H(t) = \frac{\dot{a}(t)}{a(t)},
$$
but the conformal Hubble parameter $\mathcal H$ depends on the conformal time $\eta$ and can be expressed as
$$
\mathcal H = \frac{a'(\eta)}{a(\eta)},
$$
where $a'(\eta)$ is the derivative of the scale factor with respect to the conformal time. Does Astropy provide a function to directly calculate $\mathcal H$, or is there a method to numerically derive it from the standard Hubble parameter $H(t)$ using the cosmological models defined in Astropy?
Specifically, I'd like to know how to compute $\mathcal H$ from the cosmological model, such as the LambdaCDM model, for a given redshift $z$. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

This largely seems to be about a specific piece of software, which is considered off-topic on this site (cf. guidelines here). The aspect of numerically deriving it $\mathcal{H}$ from $H(t)$ may be on topic here, however.

For astropy in particular, see https://www.astropy.org/help.html

If you know the relation between conformal and coordinate time, you should be able to just do some basic calculus to figure out the conformal Hubble parameter, no?



cciopi.py wrote: "$\rm \mathcal H=a'(\eta)/a(\eta)$ where $\rm a'(\eta)$ is the derivative of the scale factor with respect to the conformal time."

This expression for $\mathcal H$ is just the reciprocal of the comoving Hubble radius $\rm \mathcal H = H a$, so that is trivial since if you have $\rm a$ you also know $\rm H$, so you just need to multiply them. More interesting is $\rm H$ in terms of $\eta$, so I'll answer that as well although you didn't ask for it.


cciopi.py wrote: "Specifically, I'd like to know how to compute $\rm \mathcal H$
from the cosmological model, such as the ΛCDM model, for a given redshift $\rm z$."

I suppose you already know the relation $\rm a=1/(z+1)$. The particle horizon $\rm r_p$ in proper distances is the integral
$$\rm \rm r_p = a \int_0^a \frac{c}{\bar a^2 \ H(\bar a)} d \bar a = a(t)\int_0^t \frac{c}{a(\bar t)} d \bar t$$
and $\rm \eta = R_p/c$ where $\rm R_p=r_p/a$ is the particle horizon in comoving distances.

so for example if you take a radiation dominated universe where $\rm \Omega_R=1$
$$\rm H(a)=\frac{H_0}{a^2} \ \to \  a(t)=\sqrt{2 \ H_0 \ t} \ \to \ H(t)=\frac{1}{2 \ t}$$
the relation of $\rm r_p$ in terms of $\rm a$ or $\rm t$ is
$$\rm r_p = \frac{c \ a^2}{H_0} = 2 \ c \ t \  \to \  t=\frac{r_p}{2 \ c}$$
which gives the conformal time $\rm \eta$ in terms of $\rm a$ or $\rm t$
$$\rm \eta = \frac{a}{H_0} = \sqrt{\frac{2 \ t}{H_0}} \  \to \  t=\frac{H_0 \ \eta^2}{2}$$

or in a matter dominated universe where $\rm \Omega_M=1$
$$\rm H(a)=\frac{H_0}{\sqrt{a^3}} \ \to \  a(t)=\left(\frac{3 \ H_0 \ t}{2}\right)^{2/3} \  \to \  H(t)=\frac{2}{3 \ t}$$
the relation in terms of $\rm a$ or $\rm t$ is
$$\rm r_p = \frac{2  \ c \ \sqrt{a^3}}{H_0} = 3 \ c \ t \  \to \ 
 t=\frac{r_p}{3 \ c}$$
which gives the conformal time $\rm \eta$ in terms of $\rm a$ or $\rm t$
$$\rm \eta = \frac{2 \sqrt{a}}{H_0} = \sqrt[3]{\frac{12 \ t}{H_0^2}} \  \to \ 
 t=\frac{H_0^2 \ \eta^3}{12}$$

or in a dark energy dominated universe where $\rm \Omega_{\Lambda}=1$
$$\rm H(a)=H_0 \ \to \  a(t)=e^{ \ H_0 \ t} \ \to \ H(t)=H_0$$
the relation in terms of $\rm a$ or $\rm t$ is
$$\rm r_p = \frac{c \ (a-1)}{H_0} = \frac{c \ (e^{ \ H_0 \ t}-1)}{H_0} \ \to \ t=\frac{\ln(1+H_0 \ r_p/c)}{H_0}$$
which gives the conformal time $\rm \eta$ in terms of $\rm a$ or $\rm t$
$$\rm \eta = \frac{1-1/a}{\ H_0} = \frac{1-e^{-H \ t}}{H} \ \to \ t=\frac{\ln(\frac{1}{1-\eta \ H_0})}{H_0}$$

so plug the $\rm a$ or $\rm t$ of $\rm \eta$ into the equation for $\rm H(a)$, $\rm H(t)$ or whatever you need as a function of $\rm \eta$. For radiation domination this gives $\rm H=1/(H_0 \ \eta^2)$ and $\rm \mathcal H=1/\eta$, for matter domination  $\rm H=8/(H_0^2 \ \eta^3)$ and $\rm \mathcal H=2/\eta$ etc.
In the last example with dark energy domination you have to integrate $\rm \int_1^a$ instead of $\rm \int_0^a$ since $\rm a$ is never zero in such an universe, so we usually start with $\text{a=1}$ at $\text{t=0}$ in that case. For $\rm H$ this makes no difference since it's constant in that case anyway, but you might need it for the other functions. $\rm \mathcal H=H_0/(1-H_0 \ \eta)$ in that case though if you really need it.
I don't know about your program, but for my code see here. For different or mixed component universes see here for the corresponding $\rm H(t)$ or $\rm a(t)$.
In our universe with a combination of $\rm \Omega_R$, $\rm \Omega_M$ & $\rm \Omega_{\Lambda}$ there are no analytical solutions and you have to do it numerically.
If you neglect $\rm \Omega_R$ and only take $\rm \Omega_M$ & $\rm \Omega_{\Lambda}$ there is an analytical solution though, but it is not really elegant, so I won't paste it here, but you can find it in the last link above.

